# What license permits everything but gives credit?

Tags: license-recommendation

So I have been looking for a while for a License which permits basically everything but gives me credit for the original work, I have had a look at the ISC, BSM, zLib and GPL license but am not sure if I understand them correctly. In short I want a license which:

- Gives me credit for the original work.
- Does not hold me liable for any damages, indirectly or directly.
- Is provided as-is and comes with no warranty.
- Allows modification of the original source code/binary.
- Allows the sale of modified and unmodified source code/binary.
- Allows redistribution of any kind, even under different licenses.

In short, you are free to do as you like with my code.
I want my code to be open source too, so open-source licenses are fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of the many permissive licenses the ISC or MIT is one of the only that fits all you criteria. In particular `Allows redistribution of any kind, even under different licenses.` which translate in explicit legal terms as ["sublicense"](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT):

> [...] to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, **sublicense**, and/or sell copies of the Software [...]

Few other licenses have this spelled out explicitly. In particular the BSD (2 or 3 clauses) do not have an explicit [sublicensing](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause) permission (though the opinion of many is that it is implied).

Comment: Note that they are likely other candidates, but this is the most common and most popular one.

Comment: ^ and choosing the most common appropriate option is a good idea, because there's much more chance your users will already be familiar with it

Answer (score 3):

What do you think about the BSD Licence? Or the MIT Licence?

MIT:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
>   TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

see https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

The "New BSD License" or "Modified BSD License":

> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
>   modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
>   met:
>
> 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>      documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
> 3. Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
>      this software without specific prior written permission.
>      THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
>      AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
>      THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
>      PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR
>      CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
>      EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
>      PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
>      PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
>      LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
>      NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
>      SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

see https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses for an explanations of all the BSD licenses.

Comment: I do not know where you got your BSD text from, but this is not what is considered a bona fide BSD these days. This is at best some variant on the old BSD original with its infamous advertizing clause. Can you post the links?

Comment: Actually this is looks like an old bsd original from the UC circa 1990.... https://enterprise.dejacode.com/license_library/Demo/bsd-original-uc-1990/#license-text not a current bsd at all...

Comment: Sorry, I added the "New BSD License". Thanks!

Comment: The MIT license seems to be the one for me, thanks :)

Comment: If the license doesn't have a license version and the text has ever changed, I probably would never use it.